# Cannot cast my custom UIView subclass created from XIB to the class I need (only UIView)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, xib

What I've done is:

1) Created a `.xib` file `TranslationInfoWindow.xib`:

[image: xib file for the info window]

2) Created `TranslationInfoWindow.swift` file with the follow content:

```
import UIKit

class TranslationInfoWindow: UIView {

    // MARK: - Initializers

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    // MARK: - Private Helper Methods

    // Performs the initial setup.
    private func setupView() {
        let view = viewFromNibForClass()
        view.frame = bounds

        // Auto-layout stuff.
        view.autoresizingMask = [
            UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth,
            UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
        ]

        // Show the view.
        addSubview(view)
    }

    // Loads a XIB file into a view and returns this view.
    private func viewFromNibForClass() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

        return view
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var avatarImageView: RoundedImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usersLabel: UILabel!
}
```

3) Here I try to initialise my custom view:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    //             FIXME: There is a UIView but it doesn't want to be casted in TranslationInfoWindow
    if let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(
        "TranslationInfoWindow", owner: view, options: nil)?.first as? TranslationInfoWindow {
        return infoWindow
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now if I try to run the project I have the following error:
[image: My error]

What am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE:

Here's the hierarchy of xib:
[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of how your xib tree looks like. Also check that the problem is actually the cast

Comment: Show the error message in the console if you have one. Else, log (the class) of `let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner:self, options:nil).first`

Comment: @FernandoMazzon added the hierarchy of xib

Comment: class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView { return UINib(nibName: "nib file name", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView }   see this.

Comment: Could you log `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(
        "TranslationInfoWindow", owner: view, options: nil)` ?

Comment: check TranslationInfoWindow.xib for case typos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interface Builder, did you change the class name in the Identity Inspector (3rd from left) tab from UIView to your custom class name?
[image: screen grab of IB]

Comment: Only for "File'sOwner", not "View"

Comment: Try setting the name of your custom class as the value here.  I believe this is the missing piece.

Comment: are you sure? Haven't seen anyone who would recommend to set a custom class there

Comment: I don't personally use the owner. You can tie the outlets to the view itself, and then use a nil owner. For these kind of standalone view only, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the correct class  of TranslationInfoWindow.xib to be type TranslationInfoWindow in IB .

Comment: Try looping over the nibs, and choose the correct one, if type is the same as your class...instead choosing the first one.